# What did Rama tell Sita about Kaliyug?

Tags: rama, kali-yuga

I have heard some [Doha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doha_(poetry)) of Kabir ([couplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couplet)) or somewhere else like this:

> Ramchandra keh gaye siya se aisa kaliyug ayega,
>   Hans chugega dana dunaka, kauvva moti khayega

Means

> Ramchandra told Sita such kaliyug will come that a goose will eat little grains and crow will eat pearls.

Here crows means bad people and goose means good people (will have less benefits).

So what did Lord Rama tell Sita about kaliyug? Please explain.

Comment: Can you translate that into English?

Comment: I've doubt: Is this Doha of Kabir?

Comment: It is somewhere I heard it

Comment: You might heard the [Hindi film song](http://hindigeetmala.net/song/ramchander_kah_gaye_siya_se.htm) ; read lyrics to know what ram tell sita about kaliyug. I think it is only story-film song nothing relevant with Hinduism scripture. (off-topic):P

Comment: Seems like a bhajan written by lyricist [Rajendra Krishan](http://www.hindilyrics.net/lyrics/of-Ramchandra%20Keh%20Gaye%20Siyase.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's only about a song.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has not scriptural base and seems about film song.

Comment: I follow Pandya's comments